# Create new Object from Returned Method Object from in Java

Tags: java, android, oop

Hi All hope you can help.

I have a method of which returns a custom object of mine.
This object contain an ArrayList and Strings.

I want to create a new object of the same type that is returned from the method, which contains the same information that is returned.

My question is, can I just create a new instance of this Object as per below?

```
public received_data_object XmlresponseParse(String Response) { 
    received_data_object received_data_object_instance = new  received_data_object();

    //Process some XML and add the item to the list.
    received_data_object_instance.addTo_List("SomeText");

    return received_data_object_instance;
}
```

Then from the calling classes method , can I just say:

```
received_data_object received_data_object_otherInstance = new received_data_object();
received_data_object_otherInstance = XmlresponseParse("SomeXMLString");
```

What I'm concerned about is, am I actually creating a new instance of the object, or am I passing the new object a reference to the object returned and so both will now be 'linked'?

Is it best to just create my new object and then access the getters in the returned object and copy the values over to the new object?

I'm concerned, because everything says you should detach your code from methods in classes like this but at the same time, everything seems to copy by reference to the original object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read up about Java naming conventions: following them will make it much easier for other Java developers to read your code.

Comment: Don't create a new object in the calling code in the first place.  You're just throwing away the reference one line later.  You're fine just assigning your variable to the output of the parsing method.

Comment: is there more logic in `xmlResponseParse` that you are not showing? does `addTo_List` simply just add to the arraylist and nothing more. if this is the case I think extracting this out into a method is unneeded overkill. I'm a fan of clean code but i think this adds more confusion than clarity. In either case you shouldnt be creating a new instance of the object. Unless you were going for immutable objects and this wouldnt be the proper way to achieve this. What is the responsibility of  `xmlResponseParse` method

Comment: @Marquis Blount - Yes there is more code, there are XML response String variables in the object, but I didn;t show them, because they follow the same principle within the object, where I use a Set and Get for each and the ArrayList is simple, so I could easily get rid of the Method in the object.
The responsibility is to take in a string parse in he xml, pass those value to the object and then return the Object to allow me to further use those values elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @user3263740 ok I see what you are asking now. see my response

Comment: basic rule: each time you use `new` you create a new instance. Each time you use `a = b`, you assign `b` to `a` and the previous assignation of `a` is forgotten by `a`

Answer (score 2):

You have expressed `XmlresponseParse` (please change to `xmlResponseParse` method names should start with lowercase letters) contains additional code sounds like setting other variables in a `received_data_object` (please rename this to `ReceivedDataObject` first letter of objects should be Uppercase with [camalHumpNotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) per java standards).

This Answer should be based on what the responsibliy of your `xmlResponseParse` method is. Right now you are giving the method two responsibilities which are

1. Responsible for initializing `ReceivedDataObject` objects
2. Responsible for setting some or all of the fields of this Object.

This is how the decision should be made:

Are other field variables of `ReceivedDataObject` set outside of `xmlResponseParse` in the calling method? if so you should create an instance of the calling method and pass it to your `xmlResponseParse` method and operate on that instance of the object in your method **(i.e. don't use `new` in `xmlResponseParse`)**

This would look something like.

```
public void callingMethodSetSomeFields() {
        ReceivedDataObject receivedData = new ReceivedDataObject();
        // set some of the values for ReceivedDataObject in calling method
        //now set a ton of values for ReceivedDataObject using xmlResponseParse method
        xmlResponseParse(receivedData, "SomeXMLString");
    }

    public void xmlResponseParse(ReceivedDataObject receivedDataObject, String response) {
        //in here we are setting a ton of fields for receivedDataObject

        //notice we are operating on the instance of ReceivedDataObject that was passed to us.
        receivedDataObject.addToList(response);
    }
```

Or are **ALL** the field variables of `ReceivedDataObject` set inside `XmlresponseParse`? if so, use `XmlresponseParse` to create your instance of `ReceivedDataObject` in the calling method **(i.e. don't use `new` in the calling method)**

It would look like this.

```
public void callingMethodDoesntSetAnyFields(){
    ReceivedDataObject receivedData = xmlResponseParse("SomeXMLString");
}

public ReceivedDataObject xmlResponseParse(String response) {
    //in here we are setting all of the fields for receivedDataObject

    //notice we are creating an  instance of ReceivedDataObject.
    ReceivedDataObject receivedData = new ReceivedDataObject();
    receivedData.addToList(response);
    return receivedData;
}
```

Additionally, this is a situation where you can have your cake and eat it too. If you determine you need both types of `xmlResponseParse`. Lets say callingMethod1 uses the first version and some calling method2 uses the second. You can override the `xmlResponseParse` method and have both since they have different signatures.

Comment: Wow thanks for the response. I think this is actually a bit or a revelation for me on OOP.

Comment: @user3263740 No problem man if you felt this answer answered your question don't forget to upvote/accept it. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: So I guess I'm asking the obvious here, but if every time you make  new a=b you are just creating an object with a ref to the same memory space, how the heck do you ever create a real 'new' object that has its own memory space, without a reference? 
I guess passing in a reference to an object negates the need to do this in the majority of cases, but what if you subsequently want to change the values....you can't because they are now intrinsically linked to the original object. So lets say I want  new a = b, then change an Int value in a, without the Int in b changing?

Comment: @user3263740 if you want an object to have its own memory location don't point it to an existing object. Means you need to do this Obj a = new Obj();  your next question is going to be "what about if A should initially have all the same values of B"? And the answer is you need a" Deep Copy constuctor" in short it takes values from one object and stores them in another when creating the new object.  It will looks like this Obj a = new Obj(b); you will need to code the constructor.  Research deep copy vs shallow copy.

Comment: Thanks Marquis. I did some reading into Deep Copy Vs Shallow. A lot of people saying Deep copy is not a reliable method, but I think I've used it in the past without issue. I guess it's just quite a resource hungry class?

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned below creates a new object (first object):

received_data_object received_data_object_instance = new  received_data_object();

The following code would result in creation of another new object inside the method (second object):

received_data_object_otherInstance = XmlresponseParse("SomeXMLString");

When the above call returns, received_data_object_otherInstance would point to the second object. Your first object is not used anywhere and is not needed.

Therefore you just need this line and it should work fine:

received_data_object received_data_object_instance = XmlresponseParse("SomeXMLString");

Comment: This makes sense...I'm basically creating a redundant object. So can you confirm, will this new object be referencing the object that is returned form the called method?

Comment: Yes, it will. Since you are assigning the returned object from the method to the new object, the new object will point to the same object instance created in the method.